when i type flutter run i got this issue How to fix it...?
when flutter run i got the message like this ==>
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 15 Pro in debug mode...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-RunnerTests`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '11.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_analytics` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`
firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '11.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '11.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '11.0.0' defined in 'firebase_core'

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
  CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-version.yml Response: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL, retries: 4
  CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-version.yml Response: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL, retries: 3
  CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-version.yml Response: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL, retries: 2
  CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-version.yml Response: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL, retries: 1
[!] CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-version.yml Response: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:407:in `block in download_and_save_with_retries_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promises.rb:406:in `apply'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promises.rb:1205:in `apply'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promises.rb:1729:in `block (2 levels) in on_resolvable'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promises.rb:1582:in `evaluate_to'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promises.rb:1729:in `block in on_resolvable'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:363:in `run_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:352:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:335:in `loop'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:335:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `catch'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `block in create_worker'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promises.rb:1257:in `raise'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promises.rb:1257:in `wait_until_resolved!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/promises.rb:977:in `wait!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:53:in `refresh_metadata'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source.rb:31:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:30:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:315:in `block in source_from_path'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:322:in `source_from_path'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `block in aggregate_with_repos'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `map'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:331:in `aggregate_with_repos'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:26:in `aggregate'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:60:in `all'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods-core/source/manager.rb:393:in `source_with_url'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:22:in `find_or_create_source_with_url'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:179:in `block in sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `map'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:178:in `sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1081:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1080:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:125:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.15.2/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro.
Exited (1).
i couldn’t run this project on ios simulator
canyou plese help how to fix this issu ...?

what mac you use? apple silicon?

Can you share your pubspec.yaml file? Also, have you tried running this on a physical device? Or another simulator with a different OS version?

@gopelkujo m1 macbook pro

try flutter clean && rm ios/Podfile.lock && flutter pub get && cd ios && pod repo update && pod install && cd ..

[!] CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-version.yml Response: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Try running below steps:

Check ios/.symlinks/plugins contains extra plugin which you are not using.
Delete podfile.lock in ios folder, if it exists.
Delete podfile from ios folder.
Delete pods folder in ios directory.
Run flutter clean in the terminal.
Run flutter pub get in the terminal.
Run flutter run in the terminal.


Use brew installer instead:

Uninstall cocoapods by run this in terminal

gem uninstall cocoapods


Install cocoapods with brew:

brew install cocoapods

Or if you use Apple M1 you can try install by this command line
arch -x86_64 brew install cocoapods

arch -x86_64 brew reinstall cocoapods

Reference: Github Issue
